# How to display a visualization created with CartoDB in a Joomla article?

Tags: carto, joomla

The code in the article is:

```
<div id="map" style="width:600px; height:400px;"> </div>
<script>
    function main() {
        cartodb.createVis('map','http://tsubaki.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/4a9159ca-467e-11e4-80a0-0e4fddd5de28/viz.json' , {
            shareable: true,
            title: true,
            description: false,
            search: false,
            tiles_loader: false,
            center_lat: 0,
            center_lon: 0,
            zoom: 3
        })
        .done(function(vis) {
            map = vis.getNativeMap();
        })
        .error(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    window.onload = main;
</script>
```

but when I load the web page of the article I get these errors with Firebug:

> creating a layer without type
>   ..."geo/gmaps/gmaps_cartodb_layer.js","geo/gmaps/gmaps.js","ui/common/dialog.js","u...
>   cartodb.js (riga 15)
>
> TypeError: e is undefined
>       ...&")+r.join("&")},template:function(e,t){return e.replace(/{ *([\w_]+) *}/g,fun...
>   cartodb.js (linea 7, col 30868)
>
> TypeError: n.remove is not a function
>   ...ed[e]=t;if(!t)n=this.interaction[e],n&&(n.remove(),this.interaction[e]=null);els...
>   cartodb.js (linea 18, col 18443)

I don't understand...

Please someone help me!

---

This is the link of the page. Can you help me with the errors?
http://www.locattivitaecon.altervista.org/index.php/mineral-deposits-map

Comment: It would help a great deal if you told us what the `Article` actual was. A link would help ..

Comment: I can't add the link because I install joomla on local host but if there is something else I can do to help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in cartodb.js related to Array prototype modification by mootools. I fixed it, you can see it here:

https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/commit/9aebac68b32d3be25be29bc923d0e8207504f31a

It will be released soon, in the meantime you can use the development version:

http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.11.17-dev/cartodb.js

Comment: Much better. I have only one more error,could you check?

Comment: @narusegawa fixed, your map is working :) https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/commit/0e38d3305f171ae98c951359cd26a260af7f7c6c